# ajaxSubmit, IE9 and basic auth: problems uploading media

Tags: jquery, forms, upload, internet-explorer-9

We are using ajaxSubmit to handle media uploading on a project.  Here is a stripped down version of what we are doing:

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        var auth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
        data.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        // Do other stuff
    }
});
```

In other browsers, this appears to function perfectly.  In Chrome's network inspector, for example, we can see the Authorization header plain as day:

Authorization:Basic MjAwMD....etc

In IE 9 (and 8, but we don't really care about 8...) this is not the case.  When we run the request, there is no Authorization in the header and we just immediately get back a 401 error from the server due to the lack of credentials (which in turn pops up a login box to the user).

From what I have read [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload), the plugin should fallback to an iframe upload in "older" browsers.  We know that it worked in IE9 before we turned on the basic authentication, but now we have run into the issue listed above.

I am not very familiar with this area (if you couldn't tell from my meandering description of the issue), so any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.